# How to make timeit.Timer() work with output of itertools.starmap()

Tags: python-3.x, timer, partial, timeit, starmap

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around
why i can make `timeit.Timer()` work with output from
`functools.partial()` but not with output from `itertools.starmap()`.

What I basically need is `starmap(func, tuples)` to have the same 'attributes' as `partial(func, one_arg_only)`
but be more generally in the sense that I can actually pass into func multiple arguments at the same time.

What's the easiest workaround here ? 
I tried `timeit.Timer(starmap(func,tuples))` and obviously get the notorious error:

```
ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable
```

I presume this is coz starmap's output is not callable. But how do I work around this ?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show what is exactly what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itertools.starmap()` function returns an `itertools.starmap` *iterable* type whereas `functools.partial()` returns a `functools.partial` *callable* type. `timeit.Timer()` expects the first argument to be a `callable` (or a string it can `exec()`).

```py
>>> type(itertools.starmap(lambda *args: list(args), [(1, 2)])
itertools.starmap
>>> type(functools.partial(lambda x: x+1, 1))
functools.partial
```

What you want to do is create a callable that will exhaust the iterable returned by `itertools.starmap`. One way to do this would be to call the `list()` function on the output of the starmap:

```py
# This is the function to call
>>> example_func = lambda *args: len(args)

# This is the iterable that can call the example_func
>>> func_callers = itertools.starmap(example_func, [(1, 2)])

# This is the callable that actually processes func_callers
>>> execute_callers = lambda: list(func_callers)

# And finally using the timer
>>> timeit.Timer(execute_callers)
```